# float and integer formatting in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, decimal, dtype

I have a data frame that I want to format in float for one part of the data frame and whole numbers for the other part. Basically, I want to format the data frame with three decimals if the decimals are different than zero and to whole numbers if the three decimals are zeros.

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120000.0000 | 1500000.0000 | 8.343 | 2.325 | 6.453 |
| 150000.0000 | 120000.0000 | 4.875 | 3.838 | 53.348 |
| 160000.0000 | -12600000000 | 1.406 | 5.350 | 100.242 |
| 180000.0000 | -2640000.0000 | NaN | 6.863 | 147.136 |
| 210000.0000 | -4020000.0000 | -2.063 | 8.376 | 194.031 |

```
Data type
A    float64
B    float64
C    float64
D    float64
E    float64
dtype: object
```

I used the following code:

```
# Custom formatting function
def custom_format(value):
    if pd.isnull(value) or np.isinf(value):
        return value
    rounded_value = round(value, 3)
    if rounded_value == int(rounded_value):
        formatted_value = f'{int(rounded_value):.0f}'  # Show whole number only
    else:
        formatted_value = f'{rounded_value:.3f}'  # Show three decimals
    return formatted_value

# Apply custom formatting to the entire DataFrame
formatted_df = df.applymap(custom_format)

formatted_df
```

This is what I got:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120000 | 1500000 | 8.343 | 2.325 | 6.453 |
| 150000 | 120000 | 4.875 | 3.838 | 53.348 |
| 160000 | -1260000 | 1.406 | 5.350 | 100.242 |
| 180000 | -2640000 | NaN | 6.863 | 147.136 |
| 210000 | -4020000 | -2.063 | 8.376 | 194.031 |

This is what I want, however, the data type changed and become this:

```
A    object
B    object
C    object
D    object
E    object
dtype: object
```

The problem is that I need the values to be numerical while keeping the previous format. I tried multiple codes, but the object format always remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert columns back to numerical type in the end of your code

```
formatted_df = formatted_df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Comment: @Prototype51 I tried this myself and it worked, let me know if you run into any issue.